# How to add an event handler function to a prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Thanks to all who helped me out earlier tonight with my little project.

I am attempting to re-write a simple procedural program I wrote a few weeks ago using OOP javascript. The program is a reaction tester that presents a random shape to the user and measures how quickly the user clicks the shape and presents the speed. Earlier I finally managed to actually get a randomly sized and colored square to appear on the page. Now I am trying to write an event handler function that will set the css display property to none when the shape is clicked so that the shape disappears. However, the event handler function doesn't work and I have tried it a few different ways so far. See my entire code below:

```js
function Shape () {
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*1200);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
  this.draw();
}

Shape.prototype.draw = function() {
  var shapeHtml = '<div id="shape-div"></div>';
  var widthAndHeight = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
  this.shapeElement = $(shapeHtml);
  this.shapeElement.css({
    'width': widthAndHeight,
    'height': widthAndHeight,
    position: "relative",
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });
  this.shapeElement.css({
    display: "block"
  });

//Just below is where I am trying to create a function to make the shape disappear when clicked

  this.shapeElement.click(function() {
    this.shapeElement.css("display", "none");
  });

  $("body").append(this.shapeElement);
}



"use strict";
Shape.prototype.colour = function() {
  var colours = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var randomColour = "#";
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randomColour+=colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
  };
  this.shapeElement.css({backgroundColor: randomColour});
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var square = new Shape();
  square.draw();
  square.colour();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This just won't work. I am making the transition to OOP and finding it really difficult to do things that were a cinch using procedural programming. Is this typical? Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replasing:

```
this.shapeElement.click(function() {...
```

for

```
this.shapeElement.on("click",function() {...
```

You are adding this element to the DOM after it loads.
Also, check your console, because inside the event listener `this.shapeElement.css("display", "none");` probably gives you an error, `this` in that context is the element calling the event... I believe you could use:

```
$(this).css({"display": "none"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `function(){`, the inside of that function acquires a new calling context (a new `this`) depending on how it was called. But in your handler, you don't want a new `this` value - you want to *inherit* the `this` of the instantiated `Shape`. You can use an arrow function instead, or you can remember that `this` on a handler references the clicked element:

```js
function Shape () {
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*1200);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
  this.draw();
}

Shape.prototype.draw = function() {
  var shapeHtml = '<div id="shape-div"></div>';
  var widthAndHeight = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
  this.shapeElement = $(shapeHtml);
  this.shapeElement.css({
    'width': widthAndHeight,
    'height': widthAndHeight,
    position: "relative",
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
  });
  this.shapeElement.css({
    display: "block"
  });

//Just below is where I am trying to create a function to make the shape disappear when clicked

  this.shapeElement.click(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
  });

  $("body").append(this.shapeElement);
}



"use strict";
Shape.prototype.colour = function() {
  var colours = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var randomColour = "#";
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    randomColour+=colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
  };
  this.shapeElement.css({backgroundColor: randomColour});
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var square = new Shape();
  square.draw();
  square.colour();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```